# Changing Order of Integrals

Tags: integration

When I'm changing the order of integration, I always have trouble with the following:

Say we have $\int _0^3\:\int _{x^2}^9\:x^3e^{y^3}dydx$.

I draw my picture, and I try to move around the bounds now.

I run into a few conceptual problems.

1) How do I determine if I am finding the area below or above the line $y=x^3$.

2) I never know how to make the bounds on the inner integral! How do I know if it's 0 to $\sqrt{y}$ or $\sqrt{y}$ to $3$?

Comment: Maybe someone can tell me I'm wrong, but ignoring the bounds for a second I don't think you can find an elementary integration of $e^{y^3}$?

Comment: This is all about the setup

Comment: Your two questions are almost the same question. If you know what area you are integrating over, you shouldn't have any problems finding the bounds. My advice would be to look at your drawing and **for a specific $x$** marking the interval of $y$'s with a line.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the region $0 \leq x \leq 3$ $x^{2} \leq y \leq 9$ is the same as the region $0 \leq x \leq \sqrt{y}$ $0 \leq y \leq 9$ and you can change order of integration! The integral becomes $\int\limits_{0}^{9} \int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{y}} x^{3}e^{y^{3}} dxdy =\int\limits_{0}^{9}e^{y^{3}} \frac{y^{2}}{4}dy$

Comment: Why cannot I not have the bounds of the dx integral be sqrt(y) to 3?

Comment: It's not the region you will be looking for. You can sketch the intitial region and get an intuition what the new characterisation of the region will be!

Comment: When I do sketch the region, I'm having trouble determining whether it is the shaded region above or below the curve.

Comment: Ah, these problems happened to me a lot. What you can do is to chose a color first, and color the region $0 \leq x \leq 3$. (That's easier). Now to draw the region $x^{2} \leq y \leq 9$ , you draw the parabola $y=x^{2}$ and the line y=9, and you color the region is between them, using a different color. The region you want is where you have two colors!

Comment: Brilliant, thanks mich!